# How to extract only those rows of the DataFrame where the values of two columns of the DataFrame are in English Language?

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, text-mining, language-detection

I have a dataframe which has 27 columns including columns `FonctionsStagiaire` and `ExigencesParticulieres`. The dataframe has 13774 rows which are either entirely in English or French. The csv file can be found here: [GDrive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14-ge2hWvF4CyBDaFH_8snQKgKPiIcl3q/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying to keep **only** those rows of the dataframe where the values or contents of `FonctionsStagiaire` or `ExigencesParticulieres` are in English. I want to drop the **entire** rows where these columns contain values in French language.

I am using `langdetect` but is getting the error `langdetect.lang_detect_exception.LangDetectException: No features in text.` I checked out all the solutions on SO to resolve this error but nothing is working.

I also want to check for if these 2 columns contain only `NaN` values, only numeric or whitespace characters or only punctuation marks, etc. which can't be detected whether it is in English or French and might cause error while using `langdetect`.

When I am trying to see which row is throwing the error based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783383/error-using-langdetect-in-python-no-features-in-text) it is showing that `This row throws error` for every row.

I intend to use `langdetect` but any other solution would also be helpful as long as it works properly.

Any help is much appreciated.

I am trying with this code:

```
from langdetect import detect
import pandas as pd
import re
import string

def filter_nonenglish(df):
     
    list = ['FonctionsStagiaire', 'ExigencesParticulieres']

    for col in list:       
        #to check if values are only whitespaces or only numeric characters or only punctuation marks
        #something like this -> if (df[col].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric()) == True) | (df[col].apply(lambda x: x.isspace()) == True) | (all(i in string.punctuation for i in df[col]) == True):
            return False     
        else:
            #trying to use apply() to apply detect() to each <str> values of the columns and not to the entire pd.Series object
            new_df = df[(df[col].apply(detect).eq('en'))]

    return new_df
   
    #df['FonctionsStagiaire'] = df['FonctionsStagiaire'].apply(detect)
    #df['ExigencesParticulieres'] = df['ExigencesParticulieres'].apply(detect)
    
    #df = df[df['FonctionsStagiaire'] == 'en']
    #df = df[df['ExigencesParticulieres'] == 'en']
    
    #new_df = df[(df.FonctionsStagiaire.apply(detect).eq('en')) & (df.ExigencesParticulieres.apply(detect).eq('en'))]
    
df = pd.read_csv('emplois_df_parsed.csv')

df = df[df['FonctionsStagiaire'].notna() & df['ExigencesParticulieres'].notna()]   #to remove empty values

#to check whether all empty values are removed or not in the column 'FonctionsStagiaire'
#df['FonctionsStagiaire'] = df['FonctionsStagiaire'].str.lower()  
#df = df[df['FonctionsStagiaire'].str.islower()]

#to check whether all empty values are removed or not in the column 'ExigencesParticulieres'
#df['ExigencesParticulieres'] = df['ExigencesParticulieres'].str.lower()
#df = df[df['ExigencesParticulieres'].str.islower()]

#to make sure that values of both the columns are of <str> datatype
df['FonctionsStagiaire'] = pd.Series(df['FonctionsStagiaire'], dtype = "string")
df['ExigencesParticulieres'] = pd.Series(df['ExigencesParticulieres'], dtype = "string")

#bool(re.match('^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])', df.loc[:, 'FonctionsStagiaire']))
#bool(re.match('^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])', df.loc[:, 'ExigencesParticulieres']))

#   df[df[column].map(lambda x: x.isascii())]

df_new = filter_nonenglish(df)

df_new.to_csv('emplois_df_filtered.csv', index= False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but it seems like [`langdetect`](https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect) can't handle *urls* :

```
tmp = df.loc[[24], ["FonctionsStagiaire", "ExigencesParticulieres"]].T
​
                                                                       24
FonctionsStagiaire      https://www2.csrdn.qc.ca//files/jobs/P-22-875-...
ExigencesParticulieres  https://www2.csrdn.qc.ca//files/jobs/P-22-875-...
```

Using `tmp[24].apply(detect)` (*row 25*) throws a `LangDetectException: No features in text.`

An alternative would be to use [`langid`](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py) :

```
#pip install langid
from langid import classify

use_cols = ["FonctionsStagiaire", "ExigencesParticulieres"]

# checking english content
is_en = [
    classify(r)[0] == "en"
    for r in df[use_cols].fillna("").agg(" ".join, axis=1)
]

# not a null content
not_na = df[use_cols].notna().all(axis=1)

# not a random content (optional!)
not_arc = df[use_cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.fullmatch("\w+\s?\d?")).any(axis=1)

out = df.loc[is_en & not_na & ~not_arc]
```

Output :

```
print(out.loc[:, use_cols])

                            FonctionsStagiaire                   ExigencesParticulieres
11     As a Level I Technical Customer Serv...  Qualifications           Your contri...
106    What you'll create and do    Today's...  What you'll bring to this role:    A...
140    The Training Department plays a cruc...  REQUIREMENTS:            \t     Coll...
...                                        ...                                      ...
13608  CCHS Facility: Cleveland Clinic Cana...  MINIMUM QUALIFICATIONS:  · Registere...
13697                               Calculate!                          Love numbers...
13698                               Calculate!                          Love numbers...

[311 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! I had a doubt regarding `any(axis=1)` in `not_arc = df[use_cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.fullmatch("\w+\s?\d?")).any(axis=1)`. I know what `any()` does and what `axis=1` means in general but what is the usage of `any(axis=1)` in this specific case?

Comment: You're welcome ;). If you remove `any(axis)` in `not_arc` you'll get two boolean columns. So, by adding `any(axis=1)`, we check if any of those columns are `True` to flag the rows with a random content. But as I mentionnend with a comment in the code, the mask `not_arc` is optional or may need to be re-adjusted to match your needs.